# Facebook login - FB.logout() called without an access token

Tags: javascript, facebook, authentication

I keep getting the error:

> FB.logout() called without an access token.
>   The login works fine, until the page refreshes, than I get this error.
>   I cant figure out why FB.logout() doesnt work.

This is my code,I cant figure out whats the issue.

```
<script>
        /* Facebook login */
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({
                appId        : '999999999999',
                xfbml        : true,
                version      : 'v2.8' ,
                status       : true
            });
            FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
        };

        (function(d, s, id){
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

        function fblogin(){
            FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) { //Check if not already logged in
                    if(response.status != 'connected'){
                        FB.login(function(response){
                            if(response.authResponse){ // Valid login
                                var access_token = response.authResponse.accessToken;
                                FB.api('/me?fields=first_name, last_name, picture, email', function(response) {
                                    $.ajax({
                                        url     : '/account/fb_login_ajax?access_tokne=' + access_token ,
                                        method  : 'POST',
                                        dataType: 'json',
                                        data    : response,
                                        success : function( status ){
                                            if(status){
                                                window.location = '/home';
                                            }
                                        }
                                    })
                                });
                            }
                        } ,  { scope: 'public_profile,email'});
                        }else{
                        console.log("User logged alredy!");
                    }
                });
            }

            function logout(){
                FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
                    debugger;
                    if(response.status == 'connected'){
                        FB.logout(function(){
                            location = '<?php echo $logout_url; ?>';
                        });
                    }else{
                       location = '<?php echo $logout_url; ?>';
                    }
                })

            }

    </script>
```

Comment: I have never seen an access token parameter passed to FB.init, and the documentation does not mention that it would take on either. Where did you get that code from …? And why are you trying to store the access token in localStorage anyway? The JS SDK can handle the access token on its own, there should be no need for you to try and interfere with that process in the first place.

Comment: I did a php integration, which had the token in it,so putting it there was my assumption.I removed it now.But still doesnt work the way it`s supposed to.When you login its all cool, however after you refresh the page and try to obtain login status - its unknown.Even after you are clearly logged in.

Comment: Add the `status` parameter to FB.init. And btw., using FB.login like that - nested into the callback of another function - is not recommendable, it increases the chances of the popup being blocked considerably. You need to call it _directly_ on a user interaction (click) to avoid that.

Comment: Added status, updated code, still get the error.

Comment: Well do you have a properly logged in user or not? What is the result of checking the login status?

Comment: authResponse : null, status : "unknown"

Comment: Well then you need to login first.